# Exporting results of a Mysql query to excel?

Tags: mysql, excel, export

My requirement is to store the entire results of the query

```
SELECT * FROM document 
WHERE documentid IN (SELECT * FROM TaskResult WHERE taskResult = 2429)
```

to an Excel file.

Comment: Hum... it's a bit vague! Any techno, programming language, constraints, politeness, `code-style`?

Comment: You can use [Toad for MySQL (Freeware)](http://www.quest.com/toad-for-mysql) to achieve this.

Comment: @Priya, Depending on your use case, also see official [MySQL for Excel](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/).

Comment: You can [Format Table Data as Text table](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34084279/1045444).

Comment: you can simply use hold control key and click on the first row then hold shift with the control key and keep scrolling to the last row and click on it.
now you are selecting all the rows you can right click then copy row then go to excel and paste.
you can also right click on the header and copy column names

Comment: @shadysherif I'm using Sequel Pro, and the CSV export occasionally gives me grief (e.g. insufficient escaping leading to misaligned columns). For some reason, it never occurred to me to just copy/paste into Excel. Works like a charm, assuming that my clipboard/machine can handle all of the data at once. THANK YOU!

Comment: @rinogo you are welcome, Do you that my comment can be an answer?

Comment: @shadysherif - Maybe, but probably best just as a comment. It kinda assumes that someone is using a GUI, for example - something that isn't specified in the question or tags. But up to you!

Comment: I will leave it as a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 116, accepted):

The typical way to achieve this is to export to CSV and then load the CSV into Excel.

## TL;DR:

- For a **server-side** Excel-friendly CSV file from a `SELECT` query, run this:

  ```sql
  SELECT ... FROM someTable WHERE etc
  INTO OUTFILE 'someTableExport.csv' CHARACTER SET utf8mb4
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY ''
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
  ```
- For a **server-side** Excel-friendly CSV file use `mysqldump` like so:

  ```
  mysqldump -h serverHostName -u mysqlUserName -p --tab="someTableExport.csv" --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=0x22 --fields-escaped-by='' --fields-terminated-by=0x2C --lines-terminated-by=0x0D0A --databases databaseName --tables table1 table2 table3
  ```
- For a **client-side** Excel-friendly CSV file using `mysqlsh` (MySQL Shell) like so:

  ```
  mysqlsh --user="mysqlUserName" --host="serverHostName" --port=3306 --schema="databaseName"
  # Once connected, run this:
  util.exportTable("tableName", "file:///C:/Users/You/Desktop/test.csv", { dialect: "csv", fieldsEscapedBy: ""})
  ```

## First, a caution about Excel:

### Excel's vs. MySQL's default CSV formats:

Remember that Excel has its own <sub>underdocumented</sub> ideas about how CSV files should be formatted and these stand in-contrast to [MySQL's own ideas about CSV files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html); though Excel is largely compliant [with RFC 4180](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4180) you still need to prod and poke MySQL and its associated tooling to generate CSV files that Excel won't misinterpret:

|  | Excel | MySQL (default) | MySQL (when configured) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SQL `NULL` | Zero-length value | Literal `\N` | Literal `NULL` |
| Text values that don't contain commas, quotes, or line-breaks | Not enclosed | Not enclosed | Enclosed in `"` |
| Text values that contain commas, quotes, or line-breaks | Enclosed in `"` | Not enclosed | Enclosed in `"` |
| Non-text values | Not enclosed | Not enclosed | Not enclosed |
| Line-breaks and tabs in text values | Literal | Escaped as `[\r]\n` | Literal |
| Double-quotes in text values | Doubled-up `""` | Escaped as `\"` | Doubled-up `""` |
| Field separator | `,` | `\t` (Tab) | `,` |
| Record separator | `\r\n` | `\n` | `\r\n` |
| Commas inside non-quoted text values | (Results in broken table data) | Not escaped | Will always be quoted if the value contains a comma |
| UTF-8 support | - **Excel 2007-2013:** - Requires leading UTF-8 BOM - **Excel 2016+:** - Handles *BOM-less* UTF-8 <sub>with some prodding</sub> | Use `utf8mb4`. Do not specify the [older *broken* `utf8` or `utf8mb3` encodings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30074492/what-is-the-difference-between-utf8mb4-and-utf8-charsets-in-mysql). | Use `utf8mb4` |

As per the table above, MySQL *can* generate Excel-friendly CSV files, excepting that SQL `NULL`s will always be interpreted by Excel as literal text, though it's trivial to use PowerQuery or even just *Find-and-Replace* in Excel to replace them with empty cells.

### Excel and *special* CSV text markers

- [If any of your text values start with `=` then you'll need to manually fudge those as even when quoted Excel will interpret the text following `=` as a formula instead of literal text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34595812/is-a-csv-with-equal-sign-valid).
- Also watch out for [leading text like `sep=` too](https://superuser.com/questions/773644/what-is-the-sep-metadata-you-can-add-to-csvs).

### Excel and UTF-8 encoding:

Surprisingly, it wasn't until Excel was 31 years old (Excel 2016) when Excel added built-in support for UTF-8 encoding in files *without needing a BOM*, but it still defaults to importing and exporting CSV files using your system-default non-Unicode encoding (e.g. `Windows-1252`).

- When importing CSV into Excel, be sure to select Codepage `65001` for correct UTF-8 handling as Excel still defaults to non-Unicode-based codepages for some reason.

  - Note that *opening* a CSV file in Excel won't display the *Text Import Wizard*. (As of Excel 2021) you need to copy-and-paste CSV text into Excel and use the popup menu to use the legacy (*frozen-in-1994*) wizard, or use <kbd>Data > From Text/CSV</kbd> on the ribbon to use the newer (but less flexible, imo) PowerQuery-based CSV import wizard:

    - | Excel 2007-2013 | Excel 2016+ |
      | --- | --- |
      | [image] | [image] |

## Your options:

| Option | `SELECT INTO OUTFILE` | `mysqldump --tab` | `mysqldump > file.csv` | `mysqlsh` | MySQL Workbench |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Server-side CSV | **True** | **True** | **True** | **True** | Broken |
| Remote (client-side) CSV | False | False | False | **True** | Broken |
| MySQL Server version support | All versions | All versions | All versions | Only 5.7 and later | All versions |

## Option 1: Exporting an Excel-friendly CSV using `INTO OUTFILE`:

- You can do a **server-side** CSV export by using [the `INTO OUTFILE` clause of a `SELECT` query](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select-into.html).

  - Because this is "normal" SQL that's executed by the MySQL server this works regardless of whatever MySQL client tool you're using, so you don't need to install MySQL Workbench.
  - ...but because this is a server-side export you need to have permission to write to the server's filesystem which you might not have, in which case consider using specialty export tools like `mysqldump` (see below).
- MySQL's `OUTFILE` clause [has a number of **optional** subclauses](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#:%7E:text=INSERT%20Statements%E2%80%9D.-,Field%20and%20Line%20Handling,-For%20both%20the) *that must be specified* for some-level of compatibility with Excel's own CSV reader:

  - `FIELDS...`

    - `TERMINATED BY` (default: `'\t'`, for Excel use `','`)
    - `[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY` (default: `''`, should be `'"'` **with** the `OPTIONALLY` keyword)
    - `ESCAPED BY` (default: `'\\'`, for Excel use `''`)
  - `LINES...`

    - `TERMINATED BY` (default: `'\n'`, for Excel use `'\r\n'`)
    - `STARTING BY` (default: `''`, for Excel you can omit this or use the MySQL default).
  - **Do not** use `ENCLOSED BY` (without the preceding `OPTIONALLY` keyword) as that will enquote all values, regardless of type (i.e. it will enquote `int` values which will cause Excel (by default) to interpret them as text (strings) instead of numbers).
- Note that there is no option to instruct MySQL to output SQL `NULL`s as empty-fields, and so Excel will interpet them as unquoted strings of text (i.e. as `"NULL"`), so you'll want to do a Find-and-Replace in Excel after importing the file.
- If your `INTO OUTFILE <fileName>` filename (e.g. `'someTableExport.csv'` above) is not an absolute path then it will be saved into your database's `datadir` directory. Run `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';` to get the path. Note that you might not necessarily have read/write permission for new files under that directory.

So your query (`SELECT * FROM document WHERE documentid...`) would look something like this:

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    document 
WHERE
    documentid IN ( SELECT documentid FROM TaskResult WHERE taskResult = 2429 )
INTO
    OUTFILE 'someTableExport.csv'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"', ESCAPED BY ''
    LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n';
```

## Option 2: Exporting an Excel-friendly CSV using `mysqldump`:

- To store dump into CSV file using the `--tab` command-line option, [as per `mysqldump`'s documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_tab).
- **Unfortunately** `mysqldump`'s `--tab=` option **won't work** for remote MySQL servers: this is because `--tab="fileName.csv"` can only represent a path on the server.

  - While you *can* use `stdout` redirection to generate a local file (i.e. `mysqldump --etc > output.csv`) you cannot use the `--fields-terminated-by` and other format options with `stdout`, making it useless for Excel-compatible output. So if you're remote and cannot `ssh`-in then you will need to use **MySQL Shell** (`mysqlsh`) instead (see below).
- Note that `mysqldump` does not support `SELECT` queries for dumping data: it **does** support simple `WHERE`-style filters with the `--where=<expr>` option but this doesn't support things like filtering using an `INNER JOIN` (though as a workaround you could `SELECT` into a new table, then run `mysqldump` on that new table. Note that you cannot use `TEMPORARY TABLE` with `mysqldump` [as Temporary Tables are connection-scoped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567730/is-mysql-temporary-table-a-shared-resource)).

In the OP's case, due to limitations inherent in how the `--where=` command-line option works, they'll want to export both tables (`document` and `TaskResult`) and apply their filter logic in Excel PowerQuery or similar. Perform the export like so:

```
mysqldump -h serverHostName -u mysqlUserName -p --tab="someTableExport.csv" --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=0x22 --fields-escaped-by='' --fields-terminated-by=0x2C --lines-terminated-by=0x0D0A --databases databaseName --tables document TaskResult
```

- The above command-line should work *without modification* in Windows' `cmd.exe`, macOS's `zsh`, and `bash` on Linux - provided `mysqldump` is in your `PATH`.
- The use of hex-encoded chars means sidestepping the hassle of figurig out how to pass double-quotes and line-breaks as literals in your shell and terminal (`0x22` is `"`, `0x2C` is `,`, and `0x0D0A` is `\r\n`).
- **Avoid** using the `--password=<value>` (aka `-p<value>`) option on
  the `mysqldump` command-line, as it will mean your password will be saved in plaintext to your terminal or console history file, [which is an obvious massive security risk](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html).

  - So if you're in an interactive command-line session need to specify a password then `mysqldump` will prompt you for the password immediately when the program runs so it won't be saved to your history file.
  - If you want to run `mysqldump` in a non-interactive context (e.g. from within a web-application, daemon, or other process) then there's (normally) no history file to worry about, [but you should still consider alternative approaches](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/password-security-user.html) before resorting to handling passwords in an insecure way.
- If you don't specify an absolute path but use a short (unqualified) filename like `INTO OUTFILE 'output.csv'` or `INTO OUTFILE './output.csv'` theb it will store the output file to the directory specified by `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'datadir';`.

## Option 3: Exporting an Excel-friendly CSV using *MySQL Workbench*:

Unfortunately, **you can't** (unless you don't have any double-quotes anywhere in your data): As of late 2022 [MySQL Workbench has an open bug regarding its own CSV export feature: output files *never* escape double-quote characters in text](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=94735), so pretty much all CSV-handling software out there will report a malformed CSV file or import data to the wrong columns - so this makes it completely unsuitable for use with Excel.

## Option 4: Exporting an Excel-friendly CSV using *MySQL Shell* (aka `mysqlsh`):

- This is probably the simplest option, but you [might need to install the MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install.html) as it doesn't come in-box in most MySQL installations.
- MySQL Shell supports connecting to MySQL Server 5.7 and later (but not older versions). If you're still using MySQL Server 5.6 or earlier (then you *really* should update to 5.7 or later anyway) you'll have to stick with `mysqldump` run locally on the MySQL Server itself (but you can use an `ssh` session, of course).

  - The new "MySQL X" protocol (`mysqlx://user@host/schema`) is not supported by MySQL 5.7, but `mysqlsh` supports non-X connections with old-style command-line parameters.

1. [Install MySQL Shell](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-install.html) if it isn't already installed.
2. If you start *MySQL Shell* without any command-line arguments (e.g. because you use the Start Menu shortcut on Windows)) then use the `\connect` command to connect.

   - For MySQL 5.7 use `\connect mysql://username@hostname`
   - For MySQL 8.0+ there are a variety of ways to connect, including the "MySQL X" protocol as well as "Classic" connections. [Consult the docs for more info](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-commands.html#:%7E:text=Connect%2C%20Reconnect%2C%20and%20Disconnect%20Commands).
   - If your username contains literal `@` characters then you need to percent-encode them (e.g. if you're using Azure MySQL then your *full* username will be like `username%40servername@servername.mysql.database.azure.com`).
   - Immediately after you submit the `\connect` command you will be prompted for your password interactively.
3. If you can start `mysqlsh` with arguments, then you can run `mysqlsh --user="userName" --host="hostName" --port=3306 --schema="dbName"` directly without using the `\connect` command.
4. Once connected, [run the `util.exportTable(tableName, outputUri, options)` command](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-shell/8.0/en/mysql-shell-utilities-table-export.html) with the following arguments:

   - `tableName`: your table name.

     - Unfortunately there doesn't seem to be a way to apply a `WHERE` filter or export the results of a `SELECT` query, (though as with `mysqldump` you could always save your query results to a new `TABLE`, then export that table, then `DROP TABLE` when you're done with it. Remember that `TEMPORARY TABLE` won't work here as tables created in one session aren't visible from any other session - and `mysqlsh` will have its own session.
   - `outputUri`: To save the file locally use a `file:///` URI.

     - On Windows you can use a forward-slash as a directory-name separator instead of a backslash. e.g. `file:///C:/Users/Me/Desktop/export.csv`.
   - `options`: To ensure compatibility with Excel specify `{ dialect: "csv", fieldsEscapedBy: ""}`.

     - The `dialect: "csv"` option sets Excel-compatible defaults for all-but-one of the `OUTFILE` parameters, so you must also specify `fieldsEscapedBy: ""`, otherwise SQL `NULL` will be be rendered as `\N` (literally) while double-quotes and line-breaks inside text values will be backslash-escaped, which Excel doesn't support.

Comment: my columns are dismissed  what is the problem,please?

Comment: I don't understand the question. "dismissed"?

Comment: i can't see column names on cvs imported

Comment: where exactly this csv file created when running this command ?

Comment: @ram I would guess the data directory. But if you want to control that, just change the path.

Comment: Some way of putting in the first line as the column would save me a minute out of my busy schedule (of running the world).

Comment: @RolandBouman I tried the same but on production server of mine and it says as follows
Access denied for user 'User_name'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
Will you please help me that what is wrong with me?

Comment: where to store export csv file?

Comment: On my debian system I stored the OUTFILE to '/tmp/file.csv' instead of 'file.csv' since the tmp directory is writable by mysql.  Then moved the file from /tmp to my home directory.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Your second variant with mysqldump hasn't work in my case. I haven't get the file.csv on output, unfortunately.

Comment: For file location: specify  'file.csv' -to-  '/tmp/file.csv'

Comment: Very bad solution. There are differences in how MySQL exports data and how Excel interprets them. For example NULL values or multiline text columns.

Comment: @dolmen I've expanded this answer with details on MySQL vs. Excel's CSV handling and I've edited the example commands to specify options making it largely Excel-compatible.

Comment: When I tried the server-side `SELECT` query above, MySQL wouldn't double-up quotes in text values. I solved the problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76320340/4409950).

Answer (score 8):

Good Example can be when incase of writing it after the end of your query if you have joins or where close :

```
 select 'idPago','fecha','lead','idAlumno','idTipoPago','idGpo'
 union all
(select id_control_pagos, fecha, lead, id_alumno, id_concepto_pago, id_Gpo,id_Taller,
id_docente, Pagoimporte, NoFactura, FacturaImporte, Mensualidad_No, FormaPago,
Observaciones from control_pagos
into outfile 'c:\\data.csv' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n');
```

Comment: The OP was referring to Excel files not CSV.

Comment: This is probably what graham.reeds was looking for.

Answer (score 7):

Use the below query:

```
 SELECT * FROM document INTO OUTFILE 'c:/order-1.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','  
 ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I need to dump the sql result into a file on the client side.  This is the most typical use case to off load data from the database. In many situations, you don't have access to the server or don't want to write your result to the server.

```
mysql -h hostname -u username -ppwd -e "mysql simple sql statement that last for less than a line" DATABASE_NAME > outputfile_on_the.client
```

The problem comes when you have a complicated query that last for several lines; you cannot use the command line to dump the result to a file easily.  In such cases, you can put your complicated query into a file, such as  longquery_file.sql, then execute the command.

```
mysql -h hn -u un -ppwd < longquery_file.sql DBNAME > output.txt
```

This worked for me.  The only difficulty with me is the tab character; sometimes I use for group_cancat(foo SEPARATOR 0x09) will be written as
'\t' in the output file.  The 0x09 character is ASCII TAB.  But this problem is not particular to the way we dump sql results to file.  It may be related to my pager.  Let me know when you find an answer to this problem. I will update this post.

Comment: `mysql -h hn -u un -p databasename < sql_script.sql > sql_output.tab` will also work

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty way I use to export mysql output to a file is

> $ mysql <database_name> --tee=<file_path>

and then use the exported output (which you can find in `<file_path>`) wherever I want.

Note that this is the only way you have in order to avoid databases running using the `secure-file-priv` option, which prevents the usage of `INTO OUTFILE` suggested in the previous answers:

```
ERROR 1290 (HY000): The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement
```

Answer (score 0):

#### For `SHOW DATABASES` and `SHOW TABLES`

The **`INTO OUTFILE`** thing won't work for *`SHOW TABLES`* and *`SHOW DATABASES`* query.

**In that case you could do:**

1. **`SHOW DATABASES`**

```sh
mysql -u <user> -p <password> -e 'SHOW DATABASES' > <path_to_file>
```

2. **`SHOW TABLES`**

```sh
mysql -u <user> -p <password> -e 'SHOW TABLES FROM <db_name>' > <path_to_file>
```

> **Tip:** The `-e` flag stands for `execute`

*References:*

- [Show Databases/Tables INTO OUTFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33620983/10204932)
- [MYSQL --execute=statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, `INTO OUTFILE` didn't work as the MySQL user was different than the logged-in user. Also, I couldn't use inline variant as the my query was quite big.

I ended up using this and it was so much easier. This probably won't support CSV or either output, but if you need output as it is, this will work.

```
mysql> tee /tmp/my.out;
```

Source: https://alvinalexander.com/mysql/how-save-output-mysql-query-file/

Answer (score 0):

I only have *client-side* access, but were unable to run `util.exportTable`, so I used:

```bash
mysql --default-character-set=utf8mb4 -uUSERNAME -pSECRET -P3306 -hHOSTNAME -Ddatabase_name -e "SELECT * FROM table_name;" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;' | sed 's/""""/""/g;' > output.csv
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an old question, but it's still one of the first results on Google. The fastest way to do this is to link MySQL directly to Excel using ODBC queries or MySQL For Excel. The latter was mentioned in a comment to the OP, but I felt it really deserved its own answer because exporting to CSV is not the most efficient way to achieve this.

[ODBC Queries](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-wordexcel.html) - This is a little bit more complicated to setup, but it's a lot more flexible. For example, the MySQL For Excel add-in doesn't allow you to use `WHERE` clauses in the query expressions. The flexibility of this method also allows you to use the data in more complex ways.

[MySQL For Excel](https://www.mysql.com/why-mysql/windows/excel/) - Use this add-in if you don't need to do anything complex with the query or if you need to get something accomplished quickly and easily. You can make views in your database to workaround some of the query limitations.

Comment: broken link for excel