# Show Databases/Tables INTO OUTFILE

Tags: mysql, into-outfile

Is there a way of getting the output of a `SHOW DATABASES` or `SHOW TABLES` command to output to a text file, similar to how the `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE` works?

The `INTO OUTFILE` produces a syntax error when used on a `SHOW` command. I am open to external commands if there is a way to produce this using a cmdline tool such as mysqldump.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The best way to output this would be to pipe the data to a file. For instance:

```
mysql -u root -e "SHOW DATABASES" > my_outfile.txt
```

@Velko's answer is a good answer but only if you can access the server file system. If the server is on a different system than the client, piping will be the only way to get the file on the local client system.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this:

```
SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/stack.txt' FROM information_schema.TABLES GROUP BY TABLE_SCHEMA
```

Another Example:

```
SET @databasesInfo := '';
SHOW DATABASES WHERE (@databasesInfo := CONCAT(@databasesInfo, `Database`, ','));
SELECT @databasesInfo INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/so2.txt';
```

Comment: the second one is cool use of a variable I must say (except for the command at the end of the output file)

Comment: Both your solutions work, but the answer from @PressingOnAlways is simpler for my purposes. +1 for the concat-variable hack, very clever.