# Error while sending QUERY packet when SHOW TABLES LIKE

Tags: mysql

since few weeks sometimes I got the following mysql error in the application logs.

> Error while sending QUERY packet

My first idea is increasing the max_allow_packet Variable in the configuration of our percona mysql server which returns the error. I have done this now and no idea if it helps, but, what's strange: the error occurs only when querying as follow (and only sometimes):

> SHOW TABLES  LIKE "rk_temp_a7401345"

Strange because the database has round about 950 tables, but how could this be related to max_allowed_packet?

Any suggestions?

Best
Marc

Answer (score 1):

See this link to find out how big the output would be.

[Show Databases/Tables INTO OUTFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33620411/show-databases-tables-into-outfile)

In your SESSION,
`SET @max_allowed_packet=(size+10%);`
then your `SHOW TABLES` rather than using this size in your `my.cnf`/ini  which is a PER CONNECTION RAM possible requirement.

Comment: The output is empty since the Tablet does not exist.

Comment: @proxi  the word Tablet is not in any information posted that I can see.  Everything is tables oriented.

Comment: @WilsonHauck with over "30 years experience" you couldn't discern that he meant "table" and not "Tablet"?