# Does mysql have path separators functionality?

Tags: mysql, file, path, escaping

For instance, in Nodejs you have `path.sep`, in Java you have `File.separator`. Do you have something similar in mysql? If not, which would be the best way to deal with path separators in a way that works in any operating system?

I need it so I can pass correct paths to the LOAD_FILE() function without worrying about current operating system.

Answer (score 0):

I found that I could pass the value of `path.sep` or `File.separator` in a parameterized query:

```
"insert into MY_TABLE (file_contents) values (LOAD_FILE(?))", my_folder+File.separator+filename
```

Not what I was really looking for, but at least works for me.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL query to get path separator:

```sql
SELECT IF(INSTR(LOWER(@@global.version_compile_os), 'win'), '\\', '/') AS `path_separator`;
```

---

MySQL function to get path separator:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE FUNCTION `path_separator`()
RETURNS VARCHAR(1)
READS SQL DATA
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
    DECLARE `path_separator` VARCHAR(1);
    SELECT IF(INSTR(LOWER(@@global.version_compile_os), 'win'), '\\', '/') INTO `path_separator`;
    RETURN `path_separator`;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

```sql
SELECT `path_separator`();
```

---

MySQL query to build a file path:

Note: if MySQL server is running on Windows, backslashes (Windows path separator) may need to be escaped depending on your use case.

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(
    @@global.secure_file_priv,
    CONCAT_WS(
        `path_separator`(),
        'foo',
        'bar',
        'baz.csv'
    )
) AS `output_file_path`;
```

Output:

```
'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\foo\bar\baz.csv'
```

---

Example: export a CSV file.

Notes:

- Path must be in 'Uploads' directory if MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option or else you'll get, `"Error Code: 1290. The MySQL server is running with the --secure-file-priv option so it cannot execute this statement"`.
- Cannot create subdirectories in 'Uploads' directory or else you'll get, `"Error Code: 1. Can't create/write to file 'C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\Uploads\foo\bar.csv' (OS errno 2 - No such file or directory)"`.

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE `csv_export`()
BEGIN
    DECLARE csv_file_path TEXT;

    SELECT
        REPLACE(
             CONCAT(
                @@global.secure_file_priv,
                CONCAT_WS(
                    `path_separator`(),
                    'foo.csv'
                )
            ),
            '\\',
            '\\\\'
        )
    INTO csv_file_path;

    SET @sql = '
            SELECT id
            INTO
                OUTFILE ''csv_file_path''
                FIELDS TERMINATED BY '',''
                ENCLOSED BY ''"''
                LINES TERMINATED BY ''\n''
            FROM your_table
            LIMIT 1;
        ';

    SET @sql = REPLACE(@sql, "csv_file_path", csv_file_path);

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

```sql
CALL `csv_export`();
```

If you need to escape double quotes in text columns so the CSV file can be read properly by Excel, see my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76320340/4409950).