# Exporting online database using mysql query

Tags: database

I have a database called transportdb  it contains certain Datatables with some data  so now i want to export this complete MySql database with all data using sql query in Mysql

Comment: Check this query here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295228/exporting-results-of-a-mysql-query-to-excel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exporting results of a Mysql query to excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295228/exporting-results-of-a-mysql-query-to-excel)