# How to export html form data to excell

Tags: html, excel, export-to-excel, export-to-pdf

I want to be able to allow a site visitor to create a large list of items that they input into a form. of course the html table would have several columns that would be exported. I dont have any code as I am fist asking to see how I could do this so a user could export all columns and cells within an html table or similar fields layout. So what is the best way to get this done? Sorry for being vague as I though I would ask to get some direction before creating an actual html page where a user could fill in the fields. Export to pdf could be a good preferred alternative option too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ask a vague question you will get a vague answer (save my time for writing the code to the answer)

Well you need a frontend website either in Flask or Ruby on Rails or Nodejs depending on what you are good at (or php) store the user input data into some form of relational database aka mySQL and then dump the mySQL data into excel

[Exporting results of a Mysql query to excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295228/exporting-results-of-a-mysql-query-to-excel)

if your data get too big excel will die when you open the csv file there is so many way you could do this

- **Pandas** http://pandas.pydata.org/ (talk more about dataframe)
- **Flask** http://flask.pocoo.org/

if you use flask I will dump the user into a dataframe merge with the old dataframe store as pickle and use pandas to export as excel

Comment: Thanks, Il dig deeper. I am not a programmer at all.