# .Net Connection Pooling MySQL Temporary Table

Tags: mysql, .net, database-connection

We have a MySQL database which we use in our .NET MVC Web App. We implement connection pooling as it has some great performance benefits.

We also have some fairly heavy processing done in a few key stored procedures.

They create several temporary tables and user variables which remain valid for the life of a connection. However with pooling enabled these objects don't get reset / killed.

Should I just be re-initializing user variables and dropping/recreating temporary tables in this scenario?

The connections are guaranteed not to be accessed at the same time so I shouldn't have any concurrency issues when two SP's are executing/populating temporary tables etc.

Comment: I'd try to dispose temporary objects per transaction instead of per connection.

Comment: As a temp table is dropped only when the connection is closed, is not a good idea to use with connection pooling. What about a real table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So the answer was simply drop the temp table before recreating each time. There are no concurrency issues as it only ever can run one command at a time.

Comment: I can confirm that .NET connection pooling was causing issues when dealing with temporary tables as I kept getting the following error: MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException : Table 'blah' already exists. Dropping the table at the end of each query or dropping it right before creating the temporary table was the only solution that worked every time as there is no way to guarantee that the previous connection was truly closed. Interestingly if I put a very long sleep between two commands that both use the same temporary table the first connection eventually "closes" dropping the temp table.