# MySql temp table survives after connection closed (from .NET)

Tags: c#, mysql, .net

I'm creating a temporary table in MySql and expecting it to not be there after I disconnect. I've stripped everything out of my code and left only this:

```
        //create the first connection
        var connection = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        connection.Open();

        //create a temp table
        var cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE SomeDummyTable(Column1 float)";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //read the new temp table to proove it's created
        cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
        cmd.CommandText = "select * from SomeDummyTable";
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        //close and dispose of the first connection
        connection.Close();
        connection.Dispose();

        //create new connection
        MySqlConnection connection2 = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionString);
        connection2.Open();
        var cmd2 = connection2.CreateCommand();

        cmd2.CommandText = "select * from SomeDummyTable";
        //this does not throw an exception, even though SomeTable is 
        //a temp table from the previous connection
        cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

So I create a temp table using one connection, then close that connection and open another. I can see the temp table using the second connection. What gives? What am I missing?

Additionally: If I close the application and reopen it the temp table is not there. Could it be some connection pooling or something?

Comment: I don't know, but my guess is that it probably has to do with connection pooling - when you close the first connection, it re-adds the connection to the pool and the next connection probably reuses it and picks up where the other session left off.

Comment: I just edited and asked about pooling this second:) Yeah, I guess that could be it.

Comment: You don't need to add "edit" text to your question. If anyone cares, they can see your edit history.

Comment: Add `Pooling=False;` to your connection string and try your example code again.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23337944/net-connection-pooling-mysql-temporary-table.  Sounds like a bug in the mysql data provider.

Comment: @KennyEvitt yupp, it turns out it is pooling! If I turn it off in the connection string, the table isn't there the second time around! Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems like a bug with MySQL's connection pooling, or maybe the particular provider you're using. Based on what I could find in cursory search temporary tables should be dropped automatically when the connection in which they were created is closed. I would *not* expect connection pooling to alter that behavior.

Two workarounds then come to mind:

1. Explicitly drop the temporary table when you're done using it.
2. Disable connection pooling by adding `Pooling=False;` to your connection string.

[This MySQL bug report](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=77421) seems pertinent. Apparently other connection properties aren't being reset. Maybe the temporary table not being dropped immediately (or otherwise being made inaccessible to subsequent connections) is part of the same problem.

[You should report the bug.](http://bugs.mysql.com/) I searched the bugs for "temporary table connection pooling" but didn't find any that covered your scenario explicitly.

Comment: While I did not investigate in detail I appear to have just hit the same bug with MariaDB--same code worked fine against my MySQL database.  Explicitly dropping my temp table solved the problem.