# Is it possible to create queries a a temporary table generated on mySQL Workbench using MySQL Connector?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I have stablished a function in MySQL that lets me query some data by injecting other queries results into a Temporary Table.

My question is, is it possible to query said Temporary table once I've run my function using MySQL connector?

The reason I'm asking is that, while running a simple query from within python:

```
query = ("SELECT data FROM mytemporarytable")
cursor.execute(query)
cursor_buff = cursor.fetchall()
```

I'm getting the following error:

> mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1146 (42S02): Table 'mydatabase.mytemporarytable' doesn't exist

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A temporary table is only accessible in one [session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6567730/is-mysql-temporary-table-a-shared-resource), as long as you didn't create it in one you can't access it after words.

So instead of a function make a stored procedure of it.

And end it by

```
CREATE PROCEDURE procedure_name(parameter_list)
BEGIN
   CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mytemporarytable SELECT * FROM orig_tbl LIMIT 0;
   SELECT data FROM mytemporarytable;
END
```

and then

use the resutset like explained here https://stackoverflow.com/a/15320433/5193536